# How do I move individual words in a string in Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, text-object

[image]

In the above image, how can I move individual words (not letters) in a string.

For example, I only want to move the word "DISPLAY" up and down, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one simple way is this:

[image]

[image]

Here i just use the curve instances indices to move the letters.

or do you wanna do this?

[image]

or this?

[image]

or do you wanna animate?

[image]

Comment: +1 I'm glad you were quick enough with posting your answer before I came too far with my own :D (Only difference: I started with a _Translate Instances_ node instead of _Set Position_.)

Comment: Third one is perfect because it's almost procedural, as in I dont have to manually set the input character length, Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!